# Angular Unit Testing with Multiple expectGET's in a single test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test fails to correctly read the JSON in the second request

this is my Config factory

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('commercial.factories').factory('config', config);

function config($http) {

    var service = {
        GetConfig: getConfig
    };

    return service;

    function getConfig(identifier) {
        var _config = {};

        // Check for url match in mapping json file
        var urlMap = $http.get('./app/core/urlMap.json').then(function(response) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                if (identifier.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(response.data[i].url.toLowerCase()) > -1 || response.data[i].clientId === identifier) {
                    return response.data[i].contentFolder;
                }
            }
        });

        // Retrieve the config for the related client found in the url map (above)
        return urlMap.then(function(response) {

            var contentFolder = response;
            return $http.get('./content/' + response + '/config.json')

            .then(function(response) {

                if (Object.keys(_config).length === 0) {
                    _config = response.data;
                    _config.contentFolder = contentFolder;
                }

                return _config;
            });
        });
    }
}
})();
```

and my test...

```
describe('Config Factory', function() {

var configFactory;

beforeEach(inject(function(_config_) {
    configFactory = _config_;
}));

describe('GetConfig()', function() {

    it('should get the urlMap from the urlMap.json', function() {

        var identifier = '_default';
        var mockData = [{ url: identifier, contentFolder: '_default' }];

        $httpBackend.expectGET('./content/' + identifier + '/config.json');
        $httpBackend.expectGET('./app/core/urlMap.json').respond(mockData);

        var promise = configFactory.GetConfig(identifier);

        $httpBackend.flush(0);

        promise.then(function(result) {
            expect(result).toEqual(mockData);
        })

    });
});
```

});

and the config.json it trys to read...

```
{
   "clientId":34
}
```

when i run my test i get an error back from Karama saying ...

**uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**
 on line 2 of my JSON.

Im suspicious that it may have something to do with having two expectGET's in the same test but i cant be sure?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to call `json.stringify(mockData)` for the mockData, when responding from the get request. The json parser probably has problems with the single quotes in your mockData array.

I also spotted a missing `.` in your expectation:

`expect(result) toEqual(mockData);`

should be:

`expect(result).toEqual(mockData);`

Comment: would that be on the respond or the toEqual?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this was a bit of a silly mistake on my part.

I noticed that i failed to add a respond to the config.json call.  See code below.

```
it('should get the urlMap from the urlMap.json', function() {

        var identifier = '_default';
        var mockData = [{ url: identifier, contentFolder: '_default' }];
        var mockConfig = { clientId: 34 };
        $httpBackend.expectGET('./app/core/urlMap.json').respond(mockData);
        $httpBackend.expectGET('./content/' + identifier + '/config.json').respond(mockConfig);

        var promise = configFactory.GetConfig(identifier);

        $httpBackend.flush();

        promise.then(function(result) {
            expect(result).toEqual(mockData);
        })

    });
```